# SSIS package upgrade from 2012 to 2014 issues

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I've SSIS packages built in 2012 and now I've migrated those packages into a new Prod system and there Sql Server 2014 installed. The package format version also upgraded from 6 to 8 and executed through SSDT 2014 in VS 2015 and the execution is successful. But when I tried to run through command prompt with batch files, package fails.

I checked the old system the DEXEC.exe was in 110 folder and in the new Prod system the DTEXEC.exe is in folder 120. will it be the cause of failure of jobs.

Please suggest me to get rid of this jobs failure.

Comment: please paste your exact error message

Comment: Hi Raj, my current package version is 6 and when I copied it to another prod system the package version upgraded to 8 but when I run through command prompt, package  failed so I again changed that to 6 and executed the package from command prompt but got this error:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Jobs execution issue through batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279514/ssis-jobs-execution-issue-through-batch-file)

Comment: **please do not post duplicate questions**

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the project from the SSIS repository on the Sql 2012 server, upgrade the project and all packages to 2014, and deploy to the 2014 server.  just copying the package will not work.