# SSIS Jobs execution issue through batch file

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Hi I've migrated all my packages from 2012 to 2014 and created Jobs through batch files. But when I'm executing the packages through command file jobs executed successfully

command prompt syntax:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn>dtexec.exe /f "C:\CRPac
kages\Accounts.dtsx"

But same path I've copied into a batch file and when executes nothing happens. Please let me know the solutions.

Comment: Nothing happens? I'm sure something happens. How do you execute the batchfile? double click it? Does it pop up? Add `PAUSE` to the end and it will stay open and show you the error

Comment: Hi Nick,In the batch file I've given the path: dtexec.exe /f "C:\CRPac kages\Accounts.dtsx" but it throws error:Error: 2017-05-31 06:57:35.84
   Code: 0xC001700A
   Source:
   Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The version numb
er cannot be greater than current version number.
End Error
Error: 2017-05-31 06:57:35.84
   Code: 0xC0016020
   Source:
   Description: Package migration from version 8 to version 3 failed with error
0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Jobs execution through batch file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281608/ssis-jobs-execution-through-batch-file-error)

Comment: I googled the error message and got this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d509b8b6-ea0c-4240-aa72-04d34b5e2c74/the-version-number-cannot-be-greater-than-current-version-number?forum=sqlintegrationservices. You have a version mismatch somewhere. Also **please do not post duplicate questions**